# How to pass reference type into Url.Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to pass my model into `Url.Action`:

```
@Model FilterVm
@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { filter = @Model })
```

but when my method is called, I got always null in parameter

```
public ActionResult Index (FilterVm filter)
```

How can I pass my model as a parameter in Url.Action?

Comment: What's the signature Of Index Action? What are the parameters that it takes?

Comment: Please read the question in 5 row

Comment: Just `@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { Model })` but it will only work if your model contains only simple properties (complex properties of collections will not be bound)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Could you please help me with another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38847445/encoding-of-json. Thank you in advance

Comment: @Mr.Potkin, Sorry, cant help with that one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass all fields of your model separately. 
For example, if your model contain 2 fields Name and Id Url.Action must be

```
@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { Name=Model.Name, Id=Model.Id })
```

Also Model declaration in your view need to be in lower case

```
@model FilterVm
```

Comment: You do NOT need to pass them individually. `@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { Model }` works fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Unfortunately I can't give you an upvote because I need 15 reputation. But maybe I will able to do that later

Comment: I can do it now. Thanks again